# How long does it take to update my Nokia Lumia 610?

Tags: update, zune, 7.x, nokia-lumia-610

How much time can it possibly take to completely update my Nokia Lumia 610?

It has never been updated before. I bought it on August 2012, never had a clue on how to update the phone until today.

I looked on YouTube and the process looks a lot faster. Do you think it could take like hours to complete the update?

I'm afraid that there might be something wrong with my phone or laptop.

I've attached an image of how it looks like since two hours ago.

[image]

Any advice and suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last version of WP you can install on your Lumia 610 is [Windows Phone 7.8](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/lumia-software-update/).

The exact version is 7.10.8862.144, released the 14th March 2013, as you can see in the WP 7.8 [versions history table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_version_history#Table_of_versions_3).

Assuming the download doesn't take too long, the update should take 30-40 minutes.

Comment: Hi and thank you to you both! For your information, my Lumia is still in the 6 of 10 step in updating. I guess there's a LOT for it to update. Currently, I've kept my phone connected to the laptop for 12 whole hours. Is that normal?

Comment: @nurul uhm.. I think 12 hours are too much. Did you tried to restart the procedure?

Comment: I tried to update it later and it took like an hour to complete. I guess the first time was not properly set. Because the first time I did, I did not set the country of both lumia phone and my laptop to the same country.  Anyway, I really appreciate your comment. Have a nice day you both ^^